# Rename remote branch in gerrit

Tags: git, rename, gerrit

I have remote branch `ABC`, and I want to rename it to `XYZ.` I have renamed it locally.

My current branch is `XYZ`. The command below will create `XYZ` on `ABC` branch

```
git push origin XYZ:refs/for/ABC
```

How do I rename `ABC` to `XYZ` on the remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename a branch you need to create a new branch and then delete the old one, but to do that you need to have "Create Reference" permission on "refs/*" reference (probably you'll need help from Gerrit administrators).

IF YOU HAVE PERMISSION, you can do that using the web UI or using the command line.

### Web UI

To create or delete branches you need to go to Projects > List > Select project > Branches

### Command line

a) Create branch

```
git push origin ABC:XYZ
```

b) Delete branch

```
git push origin :ABC
```

Comment: Note that branch content (and change-history) in Gerrit UI is still linked to the old branch, which may be confusing.